# Convert Image from VBA Using ImageMagick

Tags: vba, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I would like to convert images downloaded from the internet[1] to JPGs with ImageMagick in VBA.  So far, I've attempted two methods that have both failed.

First, I tried using the ImageMagickObject 1.0 Type Library:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButtonOkay_Click()
    Dim sURL As String, sNetFile As String, sLocalFile As String, _
        cmd As String, RetVal As Integer, img As Object
    Set img = New ImageMagickObject.MagickImage
    sURL = UserForm1.TextBoxImgURL
    sLocalFile = "C:\temp\" & UserForm1.TextBoxName
    DownloadFile sURL, sLocalFile ' Function to download image from a URL and save it to a local directory
    RetVal = img.Convert(sLocalFile, sLocalFile & ".jpg") '<-- This line produces the error
    UserForm1.Hide
End Sub
```

This ends up giving me the following error:

[image: MSVB Error Message]

The source file ("C:\temp\image") exists, but the file that was to be created ("C\temp\image.jpg") does not.  This is very similar to the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064458/calling-imagemagick-com-from-vbscript-in-excel), but I have not been able to find a solution to that so far.

Second, I tried just calling ImageMagick using the `Shell` command:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButtonOkay_Click()
    Dim sURL As String, sNetFile As String, sLocalFile As String, _
        cmd As String, RetVal As Integer
    sURL = UserForm1.TextBoxImgURL
    sLocalFile = "C:\temp\" & UserForm1.TextBoxName
    DownloadFile sURL, sLocalFile ' Function to download image from a URL and save it to a local directory
    RetVal = Shell("convert.exe """ & sLocalFile & """ """ & sLocalFile & ".jpg""")
    UserForm1.Hide
End Sub
```

When I run this, the image gets downloaded just fine, but the image isn't converted and no error is thrown.  Furthermore, when I execute the command that the `Shell` command executes in a separate command window, the conversion happens exactly as I would expect.

So the question then seems to be why is the ImageMagick command working beautifully when it is operating in its own command prompt, but not working at all when operating from within VBA?

[1] I don't know if this is useful information or not, but I'm downloading the images from the internet programmatically, so I have no means of knowing what format I'm getting; however, the image I've been using to test this with is a PNG.

Comment: Did you try full path to the **convert.exe**?

Comment: Yes.  I did, and that didn't change the result at all.

Comment: `Shell("cmd.exe /c ""<full path to convert.exe>"" """ & sLocalFile & """ """ & sLocalFile & ".jpg""")`?

Comment: That feels like it's close to the correct answer, but when I enter `cmd.exe /c "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.2-Q16\convert.exe" "C:\temp\Image" "C:\temp\Image.jpg"` into the command line, the following error is returned: `'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Just tried it without the full path (i.e. using just `convert.exe`), and that seems to work fine.  If you post an answer with that, I'll accept it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `Shell` is really only for opening programs.  Therefore, it is necessary to actually tell it to open a command prompt and run the appropriate command.  This can be done by changing the line with the `Shell` command to the following:

```vb
RetVal = Shell("cmd.exe /c convert.exe """ & sLocalFile & """ """ & sLocalFile & ".jpg""")
```